# Full-Text Mysql with Regexp?

Tags: mysql, regex, full-text-search, sphinx

I am stuck in mysql with a regexp query that populates with a field from a join e.g.

```
... regexp concat('[0-9]{1,5} ',T2.Name)...
```

where the query ends up extracting the entire [0-9]{1,5} pattern. In other words looking for a pattern in one table populating with values from another.

The issue is that `Name` fields also have synonyms and acronyms associated with them that I indexed in Sphinx so that those searches work e.g. Sphinx search

```
Select Name from T2 where Match('@(Name) Bob')
```

The problem is I can't use the sphinx index on the mysql query to match synonyms to the Name fields and I can't use Sphinx to search on patterns, return positions or extract strings.

I remember someone mentioning MySql Full-Text search and wonder if that has the capabilities I'm looking for? In other words integrating a full-text mysql search that would both use any syonym mapping I index it with and work within a regexp pattern and substring extraction search?

Comment: MySQL does not provide any native means of extracting the substring that was matched by a pattern: the `REGEXP` operator merely returns a boolean result—true if the pattern was matched; false if it was not.  You will need to install a UDF (e.g. see [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg)) to obtain such functionality.  Chances are this problem can be better resolved by redesigning your schema.

Comment: @eggyal I get that MySql doesn't natively have a function yet I've written a query that does just that using substring_index. So my issue is not so much (or at all) 'can I extract a substring from a matched pattern' (I can and did); it is how can I utilize a full-text index on the term pushed into the regexp to take advantage of synonym indexing. In Sphinx I can easily push 'Bob' and get 'Robert' but there is no substring_index I can add to extract it nor does Sphinx work on position. So I was hoping MySql Full-Text would allow me to use the working substring extract with a full-text index

Comment: Full-text indexes, just power the MATCH() function, which like REGEXP indication if matches (actylly provides a score, can use for ordering). No real extra 'extraction' functions.

Comment: @barryhunter Sorry allow me to clarify; I have the mysql handling the pattern and I get that MATCH() can't extract. What I am trying to do is replace the part of the regex/mysqy query that does extract: `regexp concat('[0-9]{1,5} ',T2.Name)` with Match so that it will find either the Name or synonym e.g. `regexp concat('[0-9]{1,5} ',T2.Match(Name))`